# Page flipping sample code

Tags: iphone, sdk

Is there any sample code available for flipping a page like stanza and iBooks?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a couple of resources to get you started with UIScrollView paging:

- http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html
- http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html

If you mean iBooks' page curl animations on the other hand, Apple uses private APIs there, but developers have been trying to imitate them:

- http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html
- http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/
- http://github.com/brow/leaves