# show view after animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview

I am using page Curl up animation. I am showing one question on view, when i clicks on button it animates page curl up and shows black screen. But i want to show same view again with different question after page curl up. How to show same view with different question after page curl up animation?

i am using below code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"partialPageCurlUp" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    [UIView
     setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
     forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
```

just want to know what to do next?

Comment: have you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022973/page-flip-effect-in-uiscrollview?

Comment: also check this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253432/page-flipping-sample-code

Comment: check [this](http://pastebin.com/gaZUBXnf).

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations: ^{ // your animation code hear } completion:^ (BOOL finished) { if (finished) { // Your Animation Completion call back. NSLog(@"Is completed"); } } ];
```

Try this method.

Answer (score 0):

See you just need to implement few things more

Add animation Stop Selector in your existing code so that you may get the Animation finish point could display the next question

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStopFinished)];
```

`animationDidStopFinished` this would another `method` you should write some piece of code which will display another question as animation gets finished.

or use below code

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:.00 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^
   {
     //here you should write animation code 
   [UIView
      setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
      forView:self.view cache:YES];
   }

   completion:^ (BOOL finished) {

                if (finished) {
                         // Here You may show Next Question as animation  gets stop;
                     } 
               }];
```